# jQuery: placing content into a DIV on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I'm setting up a page containing a main content div and a slider (Owl Carousel) underneath that will contain images of various speakers at a convention. Using jQuery, I would like to show a quotation for each speaker that will fade in over the main div on mouseover, and fade out on mouseout.

The basic structure is as follows:

```
<div id="slider-container">
    <div id="main">
        <div class="quote-container"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="carousel-wrapper">
        <div class="owl-carousel">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/125x125">
                <p>Speaker Name 1</p>
                <p class="quote">This is a test quote</p>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/125x125">
                <p>Speaker Name 1</p>
                <p class="quote">This is another test quote</p>
            </div>
            <div>[MORE SLIDES HERE...</div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /#carousel -->    
</div><!-- /#slider-container -->
```

I have a test page set up [**here**](http://nickpish.com/_dev/mc-slider-test/) that lays out the primary components. Ideally, I'd like the quotes contained in the various instances of the `.quote` class to appear on hover in the `.quote-container` div above. The amount of text for each quote will very, and I'd like to avoid if possible having a fixed height container so that it will adapt to the length of the text-- that is with a fixed amount of padding and a white background positioned over the content of the main div (the general positioning of the quote will also remain the same for each.)

I'm hoping that achieving this effect will be relatively straightforward with jQuery. Thanks for any guidance here; and please let me know if I need to provide any further clarification with respect to what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the

with the class in the container, you could do it like this:

```
$(".slide").hover(function() {
    var clone = $(this).find(".quote").clone();
    clone.appendTo(".quote-container");
}, function(){
    $(".quote-container").html(""); // this clears the content on mouseout
});
```

you could use flex-slider, if you going for Responsive-website, im using it long time and its great...

Comment: Thanks reyaner, this also works well; I'm just wondering how to including formatting of the quote div, i.e. transparent background color and padding

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".slide").hover(function() {
    $(".quote-container").text($(".quote", this).text();
});
```

That should be what you're after.

Additional CSS styling within the hover

```
$(".slide").hover(function() {
    $(".quote-container").fadeIn(500);
    $(".quote-container").text($(".quote", this).text();
    $(".quote-container").css("background-color", "red");
}, function() {
    $(".quote-container").fadeOut(500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Rich. That works well; I'm also wondering how to best clear the contents on mouseout; I tried the following and it seems a bit problematic: `$(".slide").mouseout(function(){$(".quote-container").empty();});` I'm guessing there is probably a more elegant solution...

Comment: $(".slide").mouseout(function(){ $(".quote-container").text(""); }); Should work. You need to clear the text value within the selected container. .empty() only removes children within the element.

Comment: Ok I'll try that, thanks. The other problem I'm having is that I'd like to apply formatting to the quote div when it appears, i.e. a semi-transparent background and some padding. It seems I would need to inject the entire DIV not just the text, no?

Comment: Well instead of injecting the div, why not just apply the css directly within the hover event. I'll edit my answer to show this. Here's a link to the documentation on .css(): http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: This works well for just injecting the text, but how might I inject the block with formatting and other included content, such as information with a `<cite>` tag that resides within the `.quote` paragraph?

Comment: Maybe on the <p> tag, include a data-attribute for the author. Then within the quote container, have a placeholder <cite> element, and do the same thing that's being done to the quote by injecting .data("author").

Comment: I just updated my link above with parts of both your and reyaner's answers. It seems to work well, although perhaps not the most elegant solution. The last think I'd like is to invoke a fade-in/fade-out on mouseover/mouseout.